# Prove difference of summations $=\frac{e^2}{2}$

Tags: limits, summation

How do I prove that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{k\left(2k/n\right)^i}{n\Gamma\left(i+1\right)}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{k\left(\left(2k-1\right)/n\right)^j}{n\Gamma\left(j+1\right)}\right\}=\frac{1+e^2}{4}?
\end{align}
I have no idea how to attack this problem. I have little experience or know-how with double summations.

Comment: Well, first note that $\Gamma(n + 1) = n!$ for integer $n$, so that's a quick simplification.

Comment: @WChargin Yeah I knew that, I just choose to write them that way. I suppose either really works.

Comment: Either really works, but especially for series $n!$ is so common that the gamma notation is a bit obfuscating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First evaluate the infinite inner series for fixed $n$ and $k$. For the first one we get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{k}{n\cdot i!}\left(\frac{2k}{n}\right)^i=\frac{k}{n}\left(e^\frac{2k}{n}-1\right),\qquad(1)
$$
and for the second one
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{k}{n\cdot j!}\left(\frac{2k-1}{n}\right)^j=\frac{k}{n}\left(e^\frac{2k-1}{n}-1\right).\qquad (2)
$$
The difference (1)-(2) is
$$
\frac{k}{n}\left(e^\frac{2k}{n}-e^\frac{2k-1}{n}\right)=\frac{k}{n}\left(e^\frac{2k}{n}-e^\frac{2k-1}{n}\right)=\frac{\left(1-e^\frac{-1}{n}\right)}{n}\cdot k\sqrt[n]{e^2}^k
$$
and its sum is
$$
\frac{\left(1-e^\frac{-1}{n}\right)}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nk\sqrt[n]{e^2}^k=\left(1-e^\frac{-1}{n}\right)\frac{(n \sqrt[n]{e^2}-n-1)e^\frac{2(n+1)}{n}+\sqrt[n]{e^2}}{n(1-\sqrt[n]{e^2})^2}\to\frac{1+e^2}{4}.
$$
I got a different result, so I threw everything into Mathematica, which, however, confirmed my result... There might be a typo in the question?

Comment: Explanations for the first and second equations please?

Comment: I have just used the series for $e^x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{x^i}{i!}$, where $z=2k/n$. Note that $k/n$ is independent of $i$ and can be taken out of the sum.

Comment: Ok Thanks. +1 :)